# Hidden Linux OS

Tags: encryption, linux, veracrypt

I have been reading about creating hidden volume OS with TrueCrypt, and now with its successor, VeraCrypt.

https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=VeraCrypt%20Hidden%20Operating%20System

But I wasn't able to find a solution like this for Linux systems.

I would like to implement this with Windows as the decoy and a Debian Linux instance as the hidden system.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: This should work, but I haven't tested it (and it's really complex/incomplete): 1. randomize your hdd 2. setup a windows encrypted system at the start (or a random offset, shouldnt matter) (put the 1.5 GB loader at the start of your hdd) 3. put linux encrypted at random offset (don't overlap), dont put in partition table, instead put a dummy entry (idk what) 4. setup bootloader to for windows just chainload to the windows loader and for linux to take the offset + password and load from your linux partition, also add some other utility to bootloader to explain it

Comment: you could also have a usb to load linux (kexec would make this easy) and setup windows normally (not whole drive!)

Answer (score 1):

I initially shared the same goal when I began considering encrypting my PC. Unfortunately, after hours and hours of research, all I learned was that VeraCrypt does not currently support encrypting Linux system drives.

Ref: https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Supported%20Systems%20for%20System%20Encryption

I was also not able to find an alternative, or workaround, that would allow for a hidden Linux OS.

simply put: no... the answer is no. there does not appear to be a way to do that!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://security.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://security.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Eric G here, let me simplify my answer for you: no... the answer is no. the original question was "Does anyone know a way to do this?" and, there does not appear to be a way to do that... i simply explained that in more complex terms. apparently too complex for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use veracrypt to hide two windows but after that, using wubi installer to install a debian/ubuntu inside the hidden windows and after that, with some windows registry and boot loader tricks you could make it just bootstrapping the gnu/linux OS.