# Hidden OS: Decoy OS ≠ Hidden OS?

Tags: encryption, forensics, truecrypt

I wanted to use two different OS then two OS equal in the distinct functions:

Hidden OS: Linux

Decoy OS: Windows

Has how? because what I have read until today were processes done with even OS, I do not know why this way, but it would not be useful for me, since I need two different OS for different purposes, and I don't want to choose to have two equal OS for different functions.

Well, I have another doubt also

If I wanted that my Hidden OS were a live USB, as tails OS, has how?

If so, would the same way?

Two passwords on the boot screen, one would be for the Decoy OS (Windows) if case I were forced to enter the password, so dodging the hidden, and the other pass for Hidden OS (tails). Haha, it would great if this is possible, and I hope so! :D

or would of other way?

of course, all this to be done through truecrypt ;)

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please clarify a bit? The language is not very clear. I understand English is not your mother tongue (neither is mine) but I do not understand what "has how?" means.

Comment: What would be the point of doing this? Generally one wants to hide data or the fact that one even has data. But what's the point behind hiding an OS? An OS that's freely available and commonly used for innocuous activities.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any bootloader that will allow you to change the selected OS based on password entered alone, I would say you would need to customise a bootloader to achieve this.

This link may be of interest to you also:
[veracrypt](http://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=VeraCrypt%20Hidden%20Operating%20System)

As may this previous [Answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/85872/linux-hidden-os)